# Filtering Javascript array of objects by account type

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter

I have a javascript array that contains objects which have a few properties of which there are some booleans. I want to take the user's account type and filter out the ones that don't apply to them. I've included the filter code I have tried however it isn't working because it is filtering out if only one of the if statements come true. I understand this but am unsure how to resolve it.

Filter code

```
if(acc_type != 'Admin') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.admin != true
      })
    }
    if(acc_type != 'Manager') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.manager != true
      })
    }
```

Some objects from array this filter are acting on

```
{ header: "Management", admin: true, manage: true },
    {
        title: 'Creation Form',
        to: '/management/creation-form',
        admin: true,
        manage: true,
    },
    {
        title: 'Management',
        to: '/management',
        admin: true,
        manage: true,
    },
    { header: "Settings" },
    {
        title: 'Account',
        to: '/settings/account',
        admin: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Billing',
        to: '/billing',
        admin: true
    },
```

Comment: can you give an outcome example. I am having a hard time understanding the requirements

Comment: in your case use else items filled by manager then filled again by no manage so result is empty of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I understand:

```
this.items = this.items.filter(function(item){
  if(acc_type == 'Admin')
    return item.admin || !item.manager
  else if(acc_type == 'Manager')
    return item.manager || !item.admin
  else // any other acct
    return !item.admin && !item.manager
})
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly with what I had existing already. It also seems to work with additional account types with little changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return acc_type != 'Admin' && item.admin != true && 
           acc_type != 'Manager' && item.manager != true
  })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Simply turn around your logic to make it work.

If it is an 'Admin' account, every item having `admin: true` should be in the resulting list. If the account is is 'Manager', everything having `manage: true` should be in the resulting list.

```
if (acc_type === 'Admin') {
  this.items = this.items.filter(item => !!item.admin);
}
else if (acc_type === 'Manager') {
  this.items = this.items.filter(item => !!item.manager);
}
```

According to this, for 'Admin' accounts all entries will be in the resulting list, for 'Manager' accounts there will be only the first two entries.

Don't be confused by the `!!` - it's only a boolean conversion. For this example it can be omitted.